# Error: Cannot launch camera in React Native Using react-native-image-crop-picker

Tags: react-native

I am trying to add a function that handles opening a camera in React Native App. However, once I try to click on `Take A Photo` button, it does gives an error that says `Error: Cannot launch camera`

So here is my code for handling it:

```js
const handleTakeAPhoto = (): void => {
    askPermission(CAMERA).then(async (success) => {
      if (success) {
        try {
          const pickedImage = await ImagePicker.openCamera({
            width: 300,
            height: 300,
            cropping: true,
            mediaType: 'photo',
            cropperCircleOverlay: true,
          }) as Image;
          onSelect(pickedImage.path);
        } catch (error) {
          logError(`@CameraModal - handleTakeAPhoto: ${error}`);
        }
      } else {
        Alert.alert(strings.CameraRoll.denied, strings.CameraRoll.deniedMessage);
      }
    });
  };`
```

Could anyone please help, what could be the issue here!?

I expect the `Take a Photo` button to open a camera.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. What device are you testing on? Usually if you run through Xcode or Android Studio, you'll get better errors, especially if it's a native crash. If you do get an error this way, can you add it to your post please? More information about the current error would also help (stack trace etc).

Comment: Thank you Abe! I am using emaulator Android 11. I don't run my app through Android studio but running it in terminal. So here is the current error @CameraModal - handleTakeAPhoto: Error: Cannot launch camera

Answer (score 0):

i updated react-native-image-crop-picker to the latest version 0.39.0 and it worked properly